# Mercedes OM602 Diesel Engine removing Compressor and installing smaller belt

Tags: serpentine-belt

A friend of mine and I have installed a 1987 Mercedes 300D OM602 motor into a 1973 Mercedes W114 220D. We had to remove the AC Compressor as it would not fit. We put in a smaller serpentine belt but it is loose and screeches. Does anyone know the size of the belt w/o the AC Compressor? I am not a fan of using an anti stop slip for the belt.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you wait for an exact answer, you can use a string to measure the length.  Set it to full loose and full tight, measure both, and pick something near the full loose side of it.  Parts stores sell belts by rib count/width and length.